# need to trigger Web-Service(WSDL call) using Batch job

Tags: java, wsdl, batch-processing, scheduler, websphere-7

I need to invoke a web-service (a WSDL call) and based on the response I need to perform DB operations.

I need this entire activity to be run in Batch Job.If yes,is it possible to schedule it using Application Server ?.We use **IBM WebSphere v7** for the deployment.
It would be nice if you guide me to solve this issue.

We do not have any framework(Spring / Struts) in the project.It is consist of **pure Servlets and JSPs using Java 1.5**. We can not introduce any new framework in our application.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need jsp?

I would create a java program that would run on command line.

According to your OS, I would then schedule the job via a cron job (Unix) or task scheduler (Windows).

You can call a SOAP service using this technique for java 1.5 : 
https://technology.amis.nl/2009/06/05/publish-a-webservice-from-a-poja-plain-old-java-application-that-is-out-of-the-container-using-endpoint-class/